# how to get url link on the response of get() method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

> I am trying to upload and get a response to an image using DRF api. the images are uploaded on the specified location but what i want is to get the link of the image so that i can click on it and could see the image when i get the response. 
>   if anyone could help me rectify this problem I would really be very thankful

models.py file

```
class employees(models.Model):
name_of_employee = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
name_of_department = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
emp_id = models.IntegerField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg') 

def __str__(self):
    return '{} {}' .format(self.name_of_employee, self.name_of_department)
```

views.py file

```
class employeeList(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    employees1 = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employees1, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = employeesSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    employees1 = self.get_object(pk)
    employees1.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class employeeDetail(APIView):

def get_object(self,pk):
    try:
        return employees.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except employees.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request,pk):
    employees1 = self.get_object(pk)
    employees1 = employeesSerializer(employees1)
    return Response(employees1.data)

def put(self, request, pk):
    employees1 = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employees1, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_BAD_REQUEST)

def delete(self, request, pk):
    employees1 = self.get_object(pk)
    employees1.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers.py file

```
class employeesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

class Meta:
    model = employees
    fields = '__all__'
```

url.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^employees/', views.employeeList.as_view()),
url(r'^employees/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.employeeDetail.as_view()),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
'/static/',
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

on running the server my response is

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "image": "/media/Images/share-1.jpg",
    "name_of_employee": "Abhinav",
    "name_of_department": "electrical",
    "emp_id": 1
 },
```

now i want to get the link on image field so that i can click on it and see the stored image

thanks in advance

Comment: Please take care to properly format your code examples: Indentation seems incorrect.

Comment: while posting the codes the format is distorted to get fit in the code format.

Comment: Then you can edit your question to fix indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return the absolute instead of the relative path. I use a custom image implementation with the following serializer to return an absolute path:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_upload = serializers.ImageField(write_only=True)
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'image_upload')

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        '''
        Return an absolute url for the image
        '''
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(str(obj.image))
```

This might not be what you want because it doesn't use the same field for upload/download though.